# Make a new array with keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have data like this in one variable:

```
array(2) {
  ["fields"]=> 
      array(2){
           ...
               }
  ["price"] => int(36)
}
array(2) {
  ["fields"]=> 
      array(2){
           ...
               }
  ["price"] => int(25)
}
....
```

I need to sort this data by price. I can use `usort()` function, but I have to use an array with key and values. How can I make an array from this data?

I tried to use `array_fill()`, but the result was only the first element.

```
$item = Array("fields" => $arFields, "price" => $price_int); // this is data that I need to sort

$item1 = array_fill(0,15,$item);
```

Sort I do like this

```
function pricesort($a, $b) 
{
    if ($a["price"] == $b["price"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["price"] < $b["price"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$sort = uasort($item, "pricesort");
```

I tried array_multisort, but it made the same result with only the first value

Comment: Show your code with usort(), this might work (array_multisort would work too)

Comment: Show your original array

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking or what `usort` has to do with this.

Comment: `uasort($item1, "pricesort"); print_r($item1);` ... of course, `$item1` contains 15 identical records, so you wouldn't really know if they were sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach ($Your_array as $key => $row) {
    $price[$key]  = $row["price"]; 
}

array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $Your_array);
```

Change `SORT_DESC` to `SORT_ASC` if you want to sort in ascending order